# calling a function from edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am trying to call a function from edittext. I have no issue when I am using `extend activity` but when I am `extending AppCompatActivity` on edittext onClick method is giving error

How I am calling it -

```
<EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:hint="@string/date_hint"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editTextDate"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@android:drawable/edit_text"
            android:onClick="buttonPlanYourWeek"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:clickable="true"/>

public void buttonPlanYourWeek(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, ListOfAgentActivity.class);
    finish();
    startActivity(i);
}
```

I am getting an error :

```
Could not find a method planing_an_week(View) in the activity class android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintContextWrapper for onClick handler on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText with id 'buttonPlanYourWeek'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code

```
public void buttonPlanYourWeek() {
finish();
Intent i = new Intent(this, ListOfAgentActivity.class);    
startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: My problem is method is not calling. It is working when I try to call from an extended Activity

Comment: change :
 <EditText .../>
to
 <android.widget.EditText .../>

So Appcompat does not handle onClick anymore